# How to restrict access to private files/folders in plone 4.3

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am having trouble restricting access to certain states in a workflow, specifically private, as it is now, anyone can view these "private" files/folders and i do not want that. I have changed the group role to not have the "view" permission but this does not change anything. Is there another permission i have to change?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Comment: Well...No. Without any information/context about your Problem no it's not possible to help you. The only thing I can say is that the `View` permission handles `access` to certain objects. But you should provide more informations about your problem and what you tried so far. For Example: Which states? Which workflow? Workflow definition? Whats exactly wrong?

Comment: Andrew, I think you mean "states", not "stages", but @ebrehault's answer is correct IMO, though you may need to do a bit more background reading to help you get what you want.

Comment: yeah, thanks for letting me know i had the wrong word there, i also fixed up the question. And thank you for pointing me to the Super User site, i will use that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the ZMI / portal_workflow / Contents / your workflow / States / the state you want to customize / Permissions.
And here, the permissions are usually quite clear, like:

- Access contents information
- Add portal content
- Change portal events
- Modify portal content
- View

You just need to assign them to the appropriate roles.

If you work in a filesystem-based module, you can do the very same thing by editing the file profiles/default/workflows/your-workflow.xml (which can be exported from ZMI / portal_setup if needed).

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not providing a good quality question, i have gone through every single workflow and changed the "view" permission but everyone is still able to access the private files and folders

Comment: OK, i found out that i needed to publish and then retract it again for them to actually be hidden from users, thank you for your answer!